# Compile all jade files in folder using command prompt

Tags: pug

I am using jade, sass and compass for making HTML templates. I have install [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) software for jade compiler to work through command prompt. But its compiling only single file at a time. I want to compile all the files at once using command prompt, just like sass and compass does. I am wondering if its possible through command prompt.

Note: I am not using UI software like [Prepros](http://alphapixels.com/prepros/).

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT :-

I am using below command in command prompt to compile jade files.

```
jade -w index.jade
```

Comment: Jade accept a directory as a parameter and it should compile all the jade files templates into it. Can you write the command that are you using to try to know a little bit more about your issue?

Comment: I have updated the code plz check..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using `jade -w <<path to dir>>` where <> it is the directory were you have the jade files.

If you have sub-directories with jade files that you would to compile, as well, you can append to the path `/*`, for instance `/workspace/jadefiles/*`.

Another think that also works is to pass multiple files/directories to `jade -w` command, for instance:  `jade -w /workspace/jadefiles/snipped /workspace/jadefiles/components`

By the way, I tested them with nodejs 0.10.15 and jade 0.34.1

Comment: Hey i never think of this.. Thanks for the help. :)